# How to copy a file and create directory containing it with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an arrangement that has 3 lines, they are file paths to copy them:

- Configurations/config1.json
- Configurations/config2.json
- Configurations/config3.json

The instruction I use to copy the files is the following:

```bsh
Foreach ($i in $changes) { Copy-Item $i "C:\file\" -Recurse -Container }
```

The files have been copied successfully. My question is how to automatically create the directory `Configurations/` inside of `file/` and files inside of `Configurations/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use to New-Item to create the directories/files

```
$changes | foreach-object {
    # remove file name from path
    $pathToDir = $_.Substring($_.Length - ($_ -split "/")[-1].Length)
    
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $pathToDir
    
    # I'm not sure if you are trying to create empty files to copy from or if the files 
    # you are creating are copies, but below is where your would create/copy the files, if 
    # you clarify your question, I can update the code below to something relevant
    
    # your code
    Copy-Item $_ "C:\file\" -Recurse -Container
}
```

Comment: I have tested the code, as a result it has copied 2 files into the directory when they have to be 3. I don't know what change I should make so that all 3 can be copied into the same directory.

Thanks for the collaboration.

Comment: That seems like a weird problem, would you mind updating the question with the code you currently have.